# Smoothness of a distribution

Tags: distribution-theory

> Q: For $u\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $f\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$, if they satisfy the equation
> $$\triangle u=f,$$
> show that
> $$u\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \mathrm{sopp}(f)).$$

We first consider the version for those $f\in\mathcal{E}'(\mathcal{R}^3)$.

we can use the fundamental solution $$E=-\frac{1}{|\mathbb{S}^2|\cdot |x|}$$ of the Laplace equation. Observe that,

> Lemma.
> For $c\in\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$, $\frac{1}{|x|}*c$ is smooth on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\mathrm{supp}(c)$. 
> proof.
> We  choose a smooth function $\chi_{\varepsilon}$ satisfying
> $$\mathrm{support}(\chi_{\varepsilon})\subset B(0,2\varepsilon),\  \chi_{\varepsilon}\big |_{B(0,\varepsilon)}\equiv 1.$$
> We have $$\frac{1}{|x|}* c=\frac{\chi_{\varepsilon}}{|x|}*c+\frac{1-\chi_{\varepsilon}}{|x|}*c.$$
> The support of the first part is contained in $B(0,\varepsilon)+\mathrm{supp}(c)$, and the second part is smooth. Let $\varepsilon\to0+$, we will have done.

Since smoothness is a local property, we just need to show that, for every $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \mathrm{supp}(f)$, there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ on which the distribution $u$ is smooth. So, we choose $\varepsilon>0$, s.t. $B(x_0,2\varepsilon)\cap \mathrm{supp}(f)=\emptyset$ (this can be done since $\mathrm{supp}(f)$ is compact), and choose a smooth function $\theta$ satisfying $$0\leq \theta\leq 1, \  \mathrm{supp}(\theta)\subset B(x_0,2\varepsilon), \ \theta\big |_{B(x_0,\varepsilon)}\equiv 1.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
\theta\cdot u&=\delta_0*(\theta\cdot u)\\
&=\triangle E*(\theta\cdot u) \\
&=E*\triangle(\theta\cdot u)
\end{align*}

and
\begin{align*}
\triangle(\theta\cdot u)&=\triangle \theta+\triangle u+2\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x_i}\cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}  \\
&=f+\underbrace{\triangle \theta+2\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x_i}\cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}}_{=:g}.
\end{align*}

We can see that $\triangle(\theta\cdot u)$ has compact support, and $$g\big|_{B(0,\varepsilon)}\equiv0, $$ so that
$$B(x_0,\varepsilon)\cap \mathrm{supp}(\triangle (\theta\cdot u))=\emptyset. $$

Then we have $\theta\cdot u$ is smooth on $B(x_0,\varepsilon)$ by the lemma.

On the proof above, we have used the compactness of $\mathrm{supp}(f)$, and what should we do to prove the version for $f\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$ ?

Comment: Do you know what is *singular support*? Do you know how singular support behaves under convolution, i.e. if $u,v$ are distributions, how is $\operatorname{sing supp}(u*v)$ related to $\operatorname{sign supp}(u)$ and $\operatorname{sing supp}(v)$?

Comment: I haven't heard of this before，maybe I can try to think about the question by using  the properties about the singular support?

Comment: Definition 9.4 and Theorem 9.5 in [these lecture notes by Hasse Carlsson](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~hasse/distributioner_eng.pdf) might be useful.